# keeping the constructor correctly after inheritance

Tags: javascript

I've noticed this interesting problem:

```
function a() { this.aprop = 1; }
function b() { this.bprop = 2; }
b.prototype = new a(); // b inherits from a
var x = new b(); // create new object with the b constructor
assert(x.constructor == b); // false
assert(x.constructor == a); // true
```

As far as I know, `x.constructor` should be `b`, but it's actually `a` when `b` inherits from `a` through its prototype? Is there a way I can inherit from `a` without screwing up my constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `b.prototype.constructor` is assigned `new a().constructor` on the 3rd line.  You can change this property back on the following line:

```
function a() { this.aprop = 1; }
function b() { this.bprop = 2; }
b.prototype = new a(); // b inherits from a
b.prototype.constructor = b; // <-- add this
var x = new b(); // create new object with the b constructor
assert(x.constructor == b); // false
assert(x.constructor == a); // true
```

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible and a good idea for me to write a quick `function(target, parent)` that does those two lines?

Comment: @Delan: sure, that would be possible.